# How to Marshall a Future[Option[Foo]] class to JSON in AKKA-HTTP

Tags: json, scala, http, akka, akka-http

Im new to acala and akka, so the question may be a little silly.

I have a class:

```
case class Foo(colUNO: String, colDOS: Long)
```

I have a funtion:

```
getById() : Future[Option[Foo]]
```

And I am trying to use it in the akka-http route

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {

implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("system")
implicit val actorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

val route = pathSingleSlash {

    get {

      complete {

        val fut = getById()

        }
    }
}

Http().bindAndHandle(route,"localhost",8080)
println("server started at 8080")
```

}

But the error says:

> Error:(39, 20) type mismatch;  found   :
>   scala.concurrent.Future[Option[com.cassandra.phantom.modeling.MiTabla.User]]
>   required: akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable
>               getById(id)

**What I have to do to return a Json of Foo?**

Thanks!!

---

### RESOLUTION:

looking at: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0.3/scala/http/common/json-support.html
and adding the following code:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport
import spray.json._

trait JsonSupport extends SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val userFormat = jsonFormat2(Foo)
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem and the addition of `import spray.json._` made the difference.  Gotta import 'em all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0.3/scala/http/common/json-support.html and adding the following code:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport
import spray.json._

trait JsonSupport extends SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val userFormat = jsonFormat2(Foo)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This wil deal with your `Future` problem. And will work if you hava something which converts `Option[com.cassandra.phantom.modeling.MiTabla.User]]` to a `ToResponseMarshallable`

```
val route = pathSingleSlash {
    get { ctx =>
      ctx.complete(getById())
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Pim Verkerk !!
How can I convert Option[com.cassandra.phantom.modeling.MiTabla.User]] to a ToResponseMarshallable ??
I think I have to use the akka-http-spray-json but I don' t know how

Comment: I found the answer!! -> Resolution is in the question